# how to know php version compatiblity with plugin?

Tags: php, wordpress, version

Is there a way to know PHP version requirement of a wordpress plugin made some good times ago? I am searching for it but no luck so far.

Comment: Before installing a plugin from your admin dashboard wordpress will tell you if the plugin have been tested with your wp version and if the plugin is compatible with you wp

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile I think OP is talking about `PHP` version not `WP`

Comment: Yes I am talking about PHP version and not WP version. In fact the plugin was made by someone else and it has only been used in internal projects only.

Comment: @Junaid every wp version have minimum php version needed (eg WP Version 4.8.2 minimum php version needed is 7 or greater), therefore by checking if a plugin is compatable with your wp then by default the plugin will be compatible with php remember wp is built using php

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile Are you sure about v4.8.2's PHP compaibility? I'd suggest to check your facts again.

Comment: @Junaid its on the wp website for every version they specify which php version is needed

Comment: The [requirements page](https://wordpress.org/about/requirements/) say that it's recommended to run `PHP7 or greater` which of course every script or framework states, but WP supports to as low as `PHP 5.2.4+`

Answer (score 0):

Their is a plugin called "php  compatibility checker". By installing this we can check themes and plugins compatibility with the installed php version.

ref: https://wordpress.org/plugins/php-compatibility-checker/

Comment: Yeah I checked with it but I always get "The plugin/theme was skipped as it was too large to scan before the server killed the process.', 'php-compatibility-checker" with only that specific plugin activated. So, I am confused.

Comment: Me too. It's useless. It took over an hour to run and this was the result of every plugin scan. I have plenty of resources on my home XAMPP server.